# I have also tried to comment out line which show the error and it keep showing errors each line after that code

Tags: python, syntax-error

[My code is showing error for the print statement][1]

Img URL of my code
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AymWq.png

My code is given below

```
#OOPR-Assgn-5
#Start writing your code here
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self,vehicle_id,type,cost):
        self.__vehicle_id=vehicle_id
        self.__type=type
        self.__cost=cost
        self.__premium_amount=None
        self.__premium_percentage=None
        
    def get_type(self):
        return self.__type
      
    def get_cost(self):
         return self.__cost
         
    def get_vehcle_id(self):
        return self.__vehicle_id
        
    def set_premium_percentage(self,type):
        if get_type()=="Two Wheeler":
            self.__premium_percentage=2
        elif get_type()=="Four Wheeler":
            self.__premium_percentage=6
        else:
            return None
        
    def calculate_premium(self,cost,premium_percentage):
        self.__premium_amount=self.get_cost()*(self.get_premium_amount()/100)
        return self.__premium_amount
        
    def calculate_vehicle_cost(self,cost,premium_amount):
        vehicle_cost=self.get_cost()+self.calculate_premium(self.get_cost(),self.set_premium_percentage(type))
        return vehicle_cost
    
    def display_vehicle_details(self,vehicle_id,type,cost,vehicle_cost):
        print("Vehicle id=",str(self.get_vehcle_id())
        print("Type=",str(self.get_type()))
        print("Cost without Premium=",str(self.get_cost())
        print("Final Cost=",str(self.calculate_vehicle_cost())
        
v1=Vehicle(001,"Two Wheeler",117000)
v2=Vehicle(002,"Four Wheeler",625000)
v1.display_vehicle_details
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have unclosed brackets, that is the problem.  Starting from line 37.

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust your method to close your brackets:

```
def display_vehicle_details(self,vehicle_id,type,cost,vehicle_cost):
        print("Vehicle id=",str(self.get_vehcle_id()))
        print("Type=",str(self.get_type()))
        print("Cost without Premium=",str(self.get_cost()))
        print("Final Cost=",str(self.calculate_vehicle_cost()))
```

Then you will receive the error "SyntaxError: invalid token" for "001". You could fix that by defining 001 as a string:

```
v1=Vehicle('001',"Two Wheeler",117000)
v2=Vehicle('002',"Four Wheeler",625000)
```

The final code looks like this:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self,vehicle_id,type,cost):
        self.__vehicle_id=vehicle_id
        self.__type=type
        self.__cost=cost
        self.__premium_amount=None
        self.__premium_percentage=None
        
    def get_type(self):
        return self.__type
      
    def get_cost(self):
         return self.__cost
         
    def get_vehcle_id(self):
        return self.__vehicle_id
        
    def set_premium_percentage(self,type):
        if get_type()=="Two Wheeler":
            self.__premium_percentage=2
        elif get_type()=="Four Wheeler":
            self.__premium_percentage=6
        else:
            return None
        
    def calculate_premium(self,cost,premium_percentage):
        self.__premium_amount=self.get_cost()*(self.get_premium_amount()/100)
        return self.__premium_amount
        
    def calculate_vehicle_cost(self,cost,premium_amount):
        vehicle_cost=self.get_cost()+self.calculate_premium(self.get_cost(),self.set_premium_percentage(type))
        return vehicle_cost
    
    def display_vehicle_details(self,vehicle_id,type,cost,vehicle_cost):
        print("Vehicle id=",str(self.get_vehcle_id()))
        print("Type=",str(self.get_type()))
        print("Cost without Premium=",str(self.get_cost()))
        print("Final Cost=",str(self.calculate_vehicle_cost()))
        
v1=Vehicle('001',"Two Wheeler",117000)
v2=Vehicle('002',"Four Wheeler",625000)

v1.display_vehicle_details
```